# mysql query for category and date

Tags: mysql, wordpress

How can I query the wordpress database so that I'm only display the number of posts from a certain category starting at  a certain date?

I’ve tried something like this but it doesn’t work:

```
<?php
$user_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE term_id = '4' AND post_date >= '2014-01-01 00:00:00' " );
echo "<p>User count is {$user_count}</p>";
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use wordpress native WP-Query:

```
$args = array(
   'post_type'     => 'post',
   'date_query'    => array(
        'year '      => 2015,
   ),
   'cat'           => 5,
   'posts_per_page'=> -1
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$numberOfPosts = $query->post_count;
```

$numberOfPosts should hold the number you are looking for. Just paste this where you used your original code which you've shared with us.

Read more here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Excerpt from the above mentioned url:

> posts_per_page (int) - number of post to show per page (available with Version 2.1, replaced showposts parameter). Use 'posts_per_page'=>-1 to show all posts (the 'offset' parameter is ignored with a -1 value). Set the 'paged' parameter if pagination is off after using this parameter. Note: if the query is in a feed, wordpress overwrites this parameter with the stored 'posts_per_rss' option. To reimpose the limit, try using the 'post_limits' filter, or filter 'pre_option_posts_per_rss' and return -1

You can find a bunch of other options there aswell to tweak your query, to get the desired result. This should give the result you want for now.

Comment: I'm a wordpress beginner and that sounds very difficult ... try to understand

Comment: This is pure php. Where are you making the above stated query?

Comment: ... and a php beginner, too. I've found this code snippet and tried to keep it for my purposes

Comment: Please edit your question and state what goal you are trying to exactly achieve, and then I can perhaps help you more:)

Comment: I’m using wordpress 4.2.2 and a simple self-made theme. I want to display the number of posts from a single category, starting in 2015.

Comment: in my case "posts" are operations of the fire brigade (category-5) ... and I want to display something like this in the footer: "Number of operations in 2015: x"

Comment: thank you for the code... The correct result should be 18 ...I think the result depends on the settings in "settings:reading". I have set "Blog pages shown at most 10 pages". And then the result ($numberOfPosts) is also 10. When I increase this setting up to 20 the correct result (18) will be displayed.

Comment: any chance to fix the settings problem?

Comment: Edited the answer, it should now display all the posts it can find.

Comment: Thank you! It works! If I earnd enough reputation I'm going to vote up your answer.